# How can I get all information about my vcenters in vmware vsphere with pyvmomi

Tags: python, vmware, vsphere, pyvmomi

I can currently get info on all vms, all hosts, all "clusters" (datacenters?) and all datastores.  Is there anything else, any other managed datatype that would provide useful information.

My objective is to give my company info about the machines and utilization, but my side project is gather as much information as possible so that I can pair it with known outages and use machine learning to detect when systems or applications are likely to fail.

To be clear, right now this is how I gather information on vms

Also the print statements are just there so I can see what I want to put into a database and what I dont have a use for.

```
def vm_and_up():
    viewTypeComputeResource = [vim.ComputeResource]
    containerView = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(container, viewTypeComputeResource, recursive)  # create container view
    clusters = containerView.view
    for cluster in clusters:
        print(cluster.name)
        print(cluster.summary)
        hosts = cluster.host
        host_count = 0
        for hosts2 in hosts:
            host_count = host_count +1
            hosts_list.append(hosts2.name)
            #print(hosts2.name)
            vms = hosts2.vm
            #print('Cluster: '+cluster.name)
            #print('Host: '+hosts2.name)
#            vm_count = 0
            for vm in vms:
                print('Capability: '+ str(vm.capability))
                print('Datestore: '+ str(vm.datastore))
                #print('Config: '+ str(vm.config))
                print('Guest: '+str(vm.guest.disk))
                print('GuestDiskInfo')
                print('GuestFullName: '+str(vm.guest.guestFullName))
                print('GuestFullName')
                print('Guest: '+str(vm.guest.hostName))
                print('GuestHostName')
                print('Guest: '+str(vm.guest.ipAddress))
                print('GuestIpAddress')
                print('Guest: '+str(vm.guest.net))
                print('GuestNic')
                print('Guest: '+str(vm.resourcePool))
                print('GuestResourcePool')
                print('Guest: '+str(vm.runtime))#
                print('GuestRuntime')#
                print('Guest: '+str(vm.layout))#
                print('GuestLayout')#
                print('Guest: '+str(vm.resourcePool))
                print('GuestResourcePool')
                #print(vm.config.hardware)
```

similarly for datacenters I use

```
def see_datacenters():
    viewTypeDatacenter =[vim.Datacenter]
    containerviewDatacenter = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(container, viewTypeDatacenter, recursive)
    datacenters = containerviewDatacenter.view
    print(len(datacenters))
    for data_center in datacenters:
        data_center_name = str(data_center.name)
        print(data_center_name)
        print('data_center_name')        
        print(data_center.overallStatus)
        print('data_center.overallStatus')
        print(data_center.configStatus)
        print('data_center.configStatus')
        print(data_center.configIssue)
        print('data_center.ConfigIssue')
        print(data_center.vmFolder)
        print('data_center.vmFolder')
        print(data_center.recentTask)
        print('data_center.recentTask')
        print(data_center.configuration)
        print('data_center.configuration')
        print(data_center.datastore)
```

and for datastores

```
def see_datastores():
    viewTypeDatastore = [vim.Datastore]
    containerViewDatastore = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(container, viewTypeDatastore, recursive)  # create container view
    datastores = containerViewDatastore.view
    print(len(datastores))
    print(datastores)
    print('datastores')
    for datastore in datastores:
        print(datastore.name)
        print('name')
        print(str(datastore.browser))
        print('Browser')
        print(str(datastore.capability))
        print('Capability')
        print(str(datastore.info))
        print('Info')
        print(str(datastore.iormConfiguration))
        print('IormConfig')
        print(str(datastore.summary))
        print('Summary')
        print(str(datastore.overallStatus))
        print('Status')
        global datastore_summary_raw
        datastore_summary_raw = datastore.summary
```

for each of these, I am creating a container view, using viewtypes like [vim.Datastore], [vim.Datacenter] and [vim.ComputeResource]

are there any other major ones I should concern myself with?
Particularly, manage object types
https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22/fa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc/doc/index-mo_types.html
or 
https://pubs.vmware.com/vi-sdk/visdk250/ReferenceGuide/index-mo_types.html

Comment: Have you checked [https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/6.7/vsphere-automation-python](https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/6.7/vsphere-automation-python) and [https://github.com/openstack/deb-python-pyvmomi](https://github.com/openstack/deb-python-pyvmomi) ?